# C# + Nhibernate Eager Loading Join of unrelated Repositories?

Tags: nhibernate, orm, inner-join, repository-pattern

Been looking around for a way to do an eager loading join of entities from different SQL Databases but in the same physical server.

For related Entities (or tables), using Fetchmany will Eager Load the parent and Related Entity

```
            var list = DummyRepository.Queryable()
                      .FetchMany(nav => nav.RelatedEntity1)
                      .ToList();
```

Now, for unrelated entities, is doing a (Lambda/ LINQ) .Join the only way these 2 unrelated entities?

Comment: Do you mean unrelated entities?

Comment: ah yes, unrelated entities, regardless if in the same DB or not

Comment: Check if in your mapping are using fetch join.

Comment: i reread my original post, i already said for unrelated entities. Anyway, thank you, ill check my mappings :)

Answer (score 0):

I think is not posible use `Query` or `QueryOver` APIs with unmapped classes.

I recommend to use `session.CreateSQLQuery` or `session.GetNamedQuery` to call or create your queries in **SQL** and then use **DTOs** loaded by `AliasToBeanTransformer` like [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/06/30/ad-hoc-mapping-with-nhibernate/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%253A%20LosTechies%20%2528LosTechies%2529).

Or using `query.AddEntity` to load the result in your domain entities like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513191/nhibernate-createsqlquery).